# Knapsack or similar with no values and with limits as to which items can be assigned where?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem, np

Say I have a number of weights which I need to spread out across a finite number of knapsacks so that each knapsack has as even a distribution of weights as possible. The catch is that different weights can only be put into the first [image: n] bags, where each value of [image: n] varies for each weight.

For example, a weight might only be able to inserted into bags up to bag 4, i.e. bags 1 through 4. Another might have a limit up to 5. The goal as previously stated is to attempt an even spread across all bags, with the number of bags set by the weight with the highest limit.

Is there a name for this problem, and what algorithms exist?

EDIT: To help visualise, say I have 4 weights:

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| Weight # | Weight | Bag Limit |
+----------+--------+-----------+
|        1 |      2 |         2 |
|        2 |      3 |         3 |
|        3 |      1 |         1 |
|        4 |      2 |         4 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

A solution to the problem might look like this

```
| 1 |  |   |  |   |  |   |
| 2 |  | 3 |  | 2 |  |   |
|___|  |___|  |___|  |___|

Bag 1  Bag 2  Bag 3  Bag 4
```

Weights 3 and 1 were placed into Bag 1

Weight 2 was placed into Bag 2

Weight 4 was placed into Bag 3

Here, the load is spread as evenly as possible, and the problem is solved (although perhaps not optimally, as I did this in my head)

Hopefully this might clear up what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Do all the bags have the same capacity? What exeactly is the objective to have an 'even distribution' of weight? Is it sufficient to minimize the maximum load of the bags? Is the number of bags bounded?

Comment: @Codor Technically, the capacity of the bags is not bounded, as the goal is to spread the load of the weights across as many bags as possible. The number of bags is set by the weight which can go in the most number of bags, i.e. if one weight can go in bags 1-6, whilst others can only go in bags 5 and under, the number of bags is 6.

Answer (score 0):

I'd describe this problem as bin packing with side constraints -- a lot of NP-hard problems don't have good names because there are so many of them. I would expect the LP-based methods for packing variable-sized bins that decompose the problem into (1) a packing problem over whole bins (2) a knapsack problem within a bin to generate candidate bins to carry over reasonably well.

Comment: Bin packing does seem to somewhat fit my goal, but I'm more concerned with ensuring each bin contains an equal amount of weight than minimising the amount of bins required, as the capacity of each bin is technically not bounded.

Comment: @PaulClavier The decision problem is the same -- do the goods fit into x bins of capacity y? -- so the problems are closely related. Given a good solution to the decision problem you can search for the minimum feasible y (e.g., by binary search).

Comment: I need to investigate your idea, but hopefully it should work. You may also want to check my edit, which shows an example problem and solution.